# How to open calcultor app?

Tags: 18.04, calculator

When I clicked to open calculator app then for few seconds it is keep on loading. Then automatically it closes.

Comment: On the command line, enter `gnome-calculator`. Do you see any error messages? (You will get a number of warnings anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove calculator from snap and install calculator using `apt`:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```

Or, if you want to do it using snap and stable version does not work for you, you could try `--candidate` channel:

```
sudo snap install gnome-calculator --candidate
```

To get a list of available package channels:

```
$ snap info gnome-calculator

channels:
  latest/stable:    3.36.0+git4.51b0dc05  2020-04-24 (730) 2MB -
  latest/candidate: 3.36.0+git6.ce3683c7  2020-04-26 (734) 2MB -
  latest/beta:      ↑                                          
  latest/edge:      3.36.0+git11.84df8faa 2020-04-26 (733) 2MB -
installed:          3.36.0+git6.ce3683c7             (734) 2MB -
```

As an alternative, you could install and try different calculator applications:

```
sudo apt install qalculate
sudo apt install kcalc
```

The next command will show you a list of some available calculator applications you could choose from:

```
apt-cache search calculator | grep calculator
```

Comment: `apt purge gnome-calculator` wouldn't do anything as the preinstalled Calculator app on 18.04 is a snap one.